# Multiple SOA in one DNS linux server

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

Anyone could please clarify my query?

I have two domains like aa.com and bb.com. I like to delegate to my own DNS server, so I could create A record based on requirement.

DNS provider is ready to configure NS record and point to my DNS server. Can I configure multiple domain's SOA, A and CNAME in our own DNS server(LINUX)?

Answer (score 5):

Of course, you can serve multiple domains on a single DNS server like bind. Each domain can be defined in a separate zone file.